# US Resident Buy and Sell outide of USA- Do I owe tax other than the income tax?

Tags: income-tax, international

I am a resident of USA. I purchase goods online from a supplier in the Philippines.  My buyer is also based in the Philippines and is responsible for pick up from the supplier.   Therefore, the inventory movement is from the supplier to the buyer (both in the Philippines).

I pay income tax on taxable income [sales invoice minus cost of purchase].

Other than the income tax, do I owe other taxes in the US?  I have no employees. I already know what taxes I owe in the Philippines.

Thank you.

Comment: If you sell retail then of course you must pay sales tax.

Comment: US sales tax does not apply since the products are purchased from and sold to the Philippines.  Seems unlikely that any other US tax would apply.  Depending on the products, possibly some kind of excise tax.